# Mobclix implementation methods conflict Xcode 4.5

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.5, mobclix

Im implementing Mobclix in my app but got 2 method conflict warnings:

instance method 'mcScanCStyleComment:' in category from /Users/user/MyFolder/Myapp/Mobclix SDK/libMobclix.a(MobclixController.o) conflicts with same method from another category

instance method 'mcScanCPlusPlusStyleComment:' in category from /Users/user/Myfolder/Myapp/Mobclix SDK/libMobclix.a(MobclixController.o) conflicts with same method from another category

The app is running OK on simulator despite the warnings, but shows no test ads.

Any idea how to get rid of these warnings and show the ads?

Im using XCode 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

Just heard back from Mobclix support. The warnings are apparently a known issue, and they recommend ignoring this issue until their next release.

As far as the ads not showing, I had the same problem until they pointed out that the size of ads weren't available for the device I was using. (Was trying to use the 320x50 ads on iPad, which they deprecated. They're using 468x60 ads now).